# Use sql_last_value for more than one file: Logstah

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a jdbc config file from logstash

```
statement => "SELECT * from TEST where id > :sql_last_value"
```

which includes the above query.

Suppose i have 2 or more conf files, how to i differentiate my sql_last_value from each other?

Can i give an alias to differentiate them? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to configure a different [`last_run_metadata_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-last_run_metadata_path) value in each configuration file. For instance:

Configuration file 1:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    ...
    last_run_metadata_path => "/Users/me/.logstash_jdbc_last_run1"
    ...
  }
}
```

Configuration file 2:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    ...
    last_run_metadata_path => "/Users/me/.logstash_jdbc_last_run2"
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Val's answer is the correct way to implement various .logstash_jdbc_last_run files.

On top of this I want to give you some hints on implementing multiple jdbc input plugins in the same pipeline:

You need to keep in mind that when one input plugin throws some errors (for example the query isn't correct, the db user has no grants etc.) the **whole** pipeline will stop - not only the respective input plugin. That means you can block your other input plugin (which may work well).

So a common way to avoid this is to specify multiple pipelines with only one jdbc input plugin. You can then decide if you want to copy the rest of the plugins (filters and output) or send the incoming requests to a central processing pipeline with the pipeline output plugin.